# JoinColumn Hibernate / API

Tags: java, hibernate, api, joincolumn

I'm having the following problem: I want to simply join the table Markets (main) and Telephones, but I'm facing some problems while doing this with annotations.

I simply want to use the Comercio.id as the corresponding foreign key from Telefone.fk_id, but it doesn't recognize it. I also would like to ask if it's needed to create an Repository Interface for both classes.

EDIT. Also, how would look a POST req for such an example?

Comercio.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comercio")
public class Comercio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cnpj;
    private String endereco;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Telefone.class , mappedBy = "comercio", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Telefone> telefones;
    private String email;
```

Telefone.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "telefone")
public class Telefone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long telefone_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Comercio comercio;
    private String telefone;
```

The answer I get:

```
{
      "nome" : "Americanas",
      "cnpj" : "000",
      "endereco" : "SQN 112",
      "telefones" : [ ],
      "email" : "contato@americanas.com",
      "comercio_id" : 1
}
```

Console:

```
Hibernate: select comercio0_.id as id1_0_, comercio0_.cnpj as cnpj2_0_, comercio0_.email as email3_0_, comercio0_.endereco as endereco4_0_, comercio0_.nome as nome5_0_ from comercio comercio0_
Hibernate: select telefones0_.fk_id as fk_id3_1_0_, telefones0_.telefone_id as telefone1_1_0_, telefones0_.telefone_id as telefone1_1_1_, telefones0_.fk_id as fk_id3_1_1_, telefones0_.telefone as telefone2_1_1_ from telefone telefones0_ where telefones0_.fk_id=**?**
```

Apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that telephone is not an Entity in its own right: you will never want to query for a telefone and it only exists as part of a Comercio.

It could then be an `Embeddable` rather than an entity however as it only has one property - the number - then you can simplify to the below and map it as a collection of Strings. There is then no need for a `Telefone` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comercio")
public class Comercio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cnpj;
    private String endereco;

    @ELementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "comercio_telefone", 
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="comercio_id"))
    private List<String> telefones;

    private String email;
}
```

Comment: what triggers me is that in a relational database you couldn't have an array in a table. so it would be two different tables.

I'm gonna try it and come back here. How would a insert statement in h2 would look like? o.o insert into telefones(comercio_telefone) value ('xxx'); ?

Comment: so, it did work. just sent a json and it dealt with it. I always get impressed by these annotations.

Comment: but still, how would it be if I wanted to nest a more complex object?

Comment: when I try to use @Embadabble with address, for example, I can't persist it 
```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "cnpj": "000",
    "address": {},
    "tels": [
        "333"
    ],
    "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
}
```

the post req: 
```
{
 
 "name":"XYZ",
 "cnpj":"000",
 "address": {
  "cep" : "303030",
  "logradouro" : "xxx",
  "bairro" : "xxx",
  "cidade" : "xxx",
  "uf" : "xx" }
 ,
 "tels" : 
 [
  "333"
 ],
 "email":"xxx@gmail.com"
 
}
```

Comment: just added columns for that I guess

Comment: *so, it did work*.  You should accept the answer then and open a new question for other issues!